# Algorithm to find minimal number of sub sets where each set's sum doesn't exceed a max value

Tags: python, algorithm, set, dynamic-programming

Given an array of positive integers, find the minimum number of subsets where:

1. The sum of each element in the subset does not exceed a value, k.
2. Each element from the array is only used once in any of the subsets
3. All values in the array must present in any of the subsets.

Basically, a 'filling' algorithm but need to minimize the containers and need to ensure everything gets filled. My current idea is to sort in descending order and start creating sets when the sum exceeds k, start the next one but not sure what is the better way.

EDIT:

Ex:

```
Inputs: arr = [1,2,3,4,5], k= 10
Output: [[1,4,5], [2,3]]
# Other solutions such as [[2,3,4],[1,5]] are also acceptable
# But the important thing is the number of sets returned is 2
```

In the output sets, all 1-5 are used and used only once in the sets. Hope this clears it up.

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared some example input and output as well as any code you've written. I am not sure what you mean by *minimum number* - do you mean the unique sets? There's definitely an `itertools` solution here. Do you care about algorithmic complexity? Please be more detailed.

Comment: This is a form of an [Exact Cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) problem. A normal Exact Cover problem would just have your conditions 2 & 3, but I think it shouldn't be too hard to add condition 1.

Comment: This is the (atleast) np complete bin packing problem.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal thanks for providing the name of this problem, but doesn't seem to be a much better algorithm than reverse sort and assign. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a smarter way to just find the minimal number of sets, but here's some code which uses Knuth's Algorithm X to do the Exact Cover operation, and a function I wrote last year to generate subsets whose sums are less than a given value. My test code first finds a solution for the data given in the question, and then it finds a solution for a larger random list. It finds the solution for [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] with maximum sum 10 almost instantly, but it takes almost 20 seconds on my old 32 bit 2GHz machine to solve the larger problem.

This code just prints a single solution that is of the minimum size, but it wouldn't be hard to modify it to print all solutions that are of the minimum size.

```
""" Find the minimal number of subsets of a set of integers
    which conform to these constraints:

    The sum of each subset does not exceed a value, k.
    Each element from the full set is only used once in any of the subsets.
    All values from the full set must be present in some subset.

    See https://stackoverflow.com/q/50066757/4014959

    Uses Knuth's Algorithm X for the exact cover problem,
    using dicts instead of doubly linked circular lists.
    Written by Ali Assaf

    From http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~aassaf9/python/algorithm_x.html
    and http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~aassaf9/python/sudoku.txt

    Written by PM 2Ring 2018.04.28
"""

from itertools import product
from random import seed, sample
from operator import itemgetter

#Algorithm X functions
def solve(X, Y, solution):
    if X:
        c = min(X, key=lambda c: len(X[c]))
        for r in list(X[c]):
            solution.append(r)
            cols = select(X, Y, r)
            yield from solve(X, Y, solution)
            deselect(X, Y, r, cols)
            solution.pop()
    else:
        yield list(solution)

def select(X, Y, r):
    cols = []
    for j in Y[r]:
        for i in X[j]:
            for k in Y[i]:
                if k != j:
                    X[k].remove(i)
        cols.append(X.pop(j))
    return cols

def deselect(X, Y, r, cols):
    for j in reversed(Y[r]):
        X[j] = cols.pop()
        for i in X[j]:
            for k in Y[i]:
                if k != j:
                    X[k].add(i)

#Invert subset collection
def exact_cover(X, Y):
    newX = {j: set() for j in X}
    for i, row in Y.items():
        for j in row:
            newX[j].add(i)
    return newX

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

def subset_sums(seq, goal):
    totkey = itemgetter(1)
    # Store each subset as a (sequence, sum) tuple
    subsets = [([], 0)]
    for x in seq:
        subgoal = goal - x
        temp = []
        for subseq, subtot in subsets:
            if subtot <= subgoal:
                temp.append((subseq + [x], subtot + x))
            else:
                break
        subsets.extend(temp)
        subsets.sort(key=totkey)

    for subseq, _ in subsets:
        yield tuple(subseq)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Tests

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
k = 10
print("Numbers:", nums, "k:", k)

Y = {u: u for u in subset_sums(nums, k)}
X = exact_cover(nums, Y)
minset = min(solve(X, Y, []), key=len)
print("Minimal:", minset, len(minset))

# Now test with a larger list of random data
seed(42)
hi = 20
k = 2 * hi
size = 10

nums = sorted(sample(range(1, hi+1), size))
print("\nNumbers:", nums, "k:", k)

Y = {u: u for u in subset_sums(nums, k)}
X = exact_cover(nums, Y)
minset = min(solve(X, Y, []), key=len)
print("Minimal:", minset, len(minset))
```

**output**

```
Numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] k: 10
Minimal: [(2, 3, 5), (1, 4)] 2

Numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 11, 12, 17, 18] k: 40
Minimal: [(1, 8, 9, 18), (4, 11, 17), (2, 3, 12)] 3
```